# Random number selection at given probabilities with additional probabilities picking below a certain value matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, random

I have the following problem that I cant figure how to solve it.
I have to sample randomly a number from a matrix at given propabilities for 14 consecutive times, but in each loop I have some propabilities to reject some values.

I have to sample a value from the following (x)

```
x=10:5:120;
```

...with corresponding probabilities(p):

```
p=[0.0795 0.0439 0.0694 0.0259 0.1325 0.0181 0.0753 0.1885 0.0753 0.0145 0.1145 0.0229 0.0247 0.0295 0.0289 0.0066 0.0307 0.0054 0.0030 0.0036 0 0 0];
```

But each time (1:14) I have different probabilities (p2) picking bellow a certain value (b):

```
b=[100 80 70 50 40 20 10]; p2=[0.9970,0.9970,0.9970,0.9822,0.9496,0.6291,0.0564;0.9970,0.9881,0.9881,0.9733,0.9080,0.5935,0.0504;0.9970,0.9970,0.9703,0.9377,0.8427,0.5460,0.0445;0.997,0.9733,0.9555,0.911,0.7478,0.4926,0.0356;0.997,0.9555,0.9377,0.8754,0.6647,0.4273,0.0326;0.997,0.9674,0.908,0.8101,0.5757,0.3561,0.0297;0.9970,0.9733,0.8843,0.7864,0.5134,0.3056,0.0267;0.997,0.9496,0.8813,0.7596,0.4777,0.273,0.0267;0.997,0.9614,0.8783,0.7478,0.4481,0.2493,0.0237;0.997,0.9674,0.8754,0.7359,0.4273,0.2255,0.0208;0.997,0.9763,0.8843,0.73,0.4095,0.2107,0.0208;0.997,0.9792,0.8724,0.7211,0.3947,0.2018,0.0208;0.997,0.9763,0.8694,0.7181,0.3858,0.1958,0.0237;0.997,0.9525,0.8694,0.7151,0.3739,0.1869,0.0267;];
```

To give you an example: In the 4th repeat, I have to pick a number from matrix x with the probabilities given from matrix p AND I've got  0.9970 probability to pick a number bellow 100, 0.9733 to pick bellow 80, 0.9555 bellow 70, 0.9110 bellow 50,.., etc

If you need any clarification, please feel free to comment!
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Anything in particular you've tried so far?

Comment: Well, I tried to create the random numbers with the given probabilties, but its not correct: for i=1:14; R(i) = x( sum( (rand(1) >= cumsum(p./sum(p)))) + 1 );  end

Comment: have you looked at `randsample`?

Comment: I tried using randsamle, I suppose not correctly, because when i run the same process for generating 1000 random numbers with the probabilities given the results are wrong: for i=1:1000
y(i)=randsample(x,1,true,p);
end; tabulate(y)

Comment: Now, I think I used it correctly, first I normalized p, as p=p./(sum(p)); and then I used y=randsample(x,10000,true,p); The results were pretty similar to the probabilities given. Now I have to add the restrictions in each one of the the loops given by the probabilities p2 and table b